# Is there any way to read raster path in POSTGRES and bring to QGIS screen

Tags: qgis, raster, postgresql, file-path

`.qlr` or `.vrt` files contain a list of raster files path such as : `'C://raster/NYK.tiff'....'C://raster/CAL.tiff'....` etc...

QGIS displays them by reading the embedded paths.

I would like to store these path in a Postgres table. Is there any way for QGIS to read the paths from such table and to display the raster? Let's note that I don't want to store the raster themselves in the DB, only their path.

Comment: Question titles should not have more information than the question body. Please [Edit] your question to contain a number of paragraphs describing your problem, then rewrite the title to precis the topic, not ask the question. It would also help to take the [Tour].

Comment: Yes Luke: Exactly.

Comment: You can use [`raster2pgsql`](https://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html#RT_Raster_Loader) with the `-R`, `--register` flag to load the rasters as out of DB file system rasters.